# How to fix "incompatible integer to pointer conversion" in C

Tags: c

I am trying to write C code to accept characters from a user one by one and then store them into a character array. If the user enters "1" I want the loop to terminate.
The problem is that when I run the program, it just terminates and I get an error saying:

```
incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char'
      to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with &
      [-Wint-conversion]
    while (strcmp(ch, "1") != 0)
```

How do I correct this? BTW, I'm using the WinGW-w64 compiler for Windows 10.

I have this code thus far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    char ch, string[MAX];

    while (strcmp(ch, "1") != 0)
    {
        printf("Enter a character: ");
        scanf("%c", &ch);
        fflush(stdin);

        string[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }

    printf("%c", string[0]);
}
```

Comment: `while (strcmp(ch, "1") != 0)` -> `while (ch != '1')`

Comment: Please don't tag c++ in c questions, they're separate languages

Comment: As you have already been answered, `strcmp` is a function which compares 2 strings. The function expects to receive two `const char *`, but one of your arguments is a `char`.

Answer (score 3):

You have *one* character. `strcmp` requires a pointer to a *sequence* of characters that end with 0.

The easiest thing is to compare your one character to one character

```
while (ch != '1')
```

Comment: Another issue remains with `char ch; ... while (ch != '1')`, the initial value of `ch` is indeterminant.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

Solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100
    
    int main(void)
    {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
    
        char ch[MAX] = {0}, finalResult[MAX] = {0};
    
        //type cast with the strcmp argument
        //as per the function defination @strcmp will take "const char *", argument type
        while (strcmp((const char*)&ch, "1") != 0)
        {
            printf("Enter a character: ");
    
            scanf("%c", ch);   //as you are reading one 1 character so
    
            fflush(stdin);
    
            finalResult[j++] = ch[0];  //update user input character to the destination buffer
    
            i++; //increment for the putting '\0' to compare with "1"
    
            ch[i] = '\0';  //add null
    
        }
    
        printf("%c", finalResult[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Strictly speaking `(const char*)&ch` is wrong. If you take `&ch` where `ch` is an array, you get a pointer to the array of type `char (*)[MAX]`. This pointer is not compatible with `const char*`. So just drop the `&ch` and use `ch`.

Comment: Let me clear why i took (const char *)&ch, first char ch[MAX] is local variable and function need a pointer argument so if you want to pass the local variable to any pointer function how you will pass it ? does typecast is necessary ? if not passing the location variable without casting does it work fine ? or garbage will come ?

Comment: Arrays decay into a pointer to the first element whenever used in a normal expression like `strcmp(ch, "1")`. Pretty much the only exception to that array decay rule is when you use `&` on an array, which there is almost never a reason to do. Study arrays and pointers in your favourite C programming book.